# Program to Simulate 2 Coins Being Flipped at the Same Time

Tags: python

My assignment is to create a program that simulates 2 coins being tossed at the same time. If both heads, then Group A gets a point; if both tails then Group B gets a point. If the coins are different then the Prof gets a point. The program must take 2 inputs: number of games and number of tosses per game. Here are 2 separate sample runs to illustrate:

```
How many games? 1
How many coin tosses per game? 100
Game 0:
 Group A: 25 (25.0%); Group B: 19 (19.0%); Prof: 56 (56.0%)
Wins: Group A=0 (0.0%); Group B=0 (0.0%); Prof=1 (100.0%)

How many games? 5
How many coin tosses per game? 10
Game 0:
 Group A: 3 (30.0%); Group B: 1 (10.0%); Prof: 6 (60.0%)
Game 1:
 Group A: 6 (60.0%); Group B: 1 (10.0%); Prof: 3 (30.0%)
Game 2:
 Group A: 4 (40.0%); Group B: 1 (10.0%); Prof: 5 (50.0%)
Game 3:
 Group A: 4 (40.0%); Group B: 1 (10.0%); Prof: 5 (50.0%)
Game 4:
 Group A: 5 (50.0%); Group B: 3 (30.0%); Prof: 2 (20.0%)
Wins: Group A=2 (40.0%); Group B=0 (0.0%); Prof=3 (60.0%)
```

My code (albeit clunky) works for taking the inputs, simulating coin tosses, and calculating and displaying the number of points per group and the percent. My problem however, is in calculating and storing the number of wins across all of the games played. Here is my code as of now:

```
import random

def coinFlip():
    games = input("How many games? ")
    tosses = input("How many coin tosses per game? ")

    for i in range(games):
        gA = 0
        gAW = 0
        gB = 0
        gBW = 0
        prof = 0
        profW = 0

        for j in range(tosses):
            flip1 = random.randint(0, 1)
            flip2 = random.randint(0, 1)

            if (flip1 == 0 and flip2 == 0):
                gA += 1
            elif (flip1 == 1 and flip2 == 1):
                gB += 1
            else:
                prof += 1

            gAper = ((gA * 1.0) / tosses) * 100
            gBper = ((gB * 1.0) / tosses) * 100
            profper = ((prof * 1.0) / tosses) * 100

        if (gA > gB and gA > prof):
            gAW += 1
        elif (gB > gA and gB > prof):
            gBW += 1
        elif ( prof > gA and prof > gB):
            profW += 1

        gAWper = ((gAW * 1.0) / games) * 100
        gBWper = ((gBW * 1.0) / games) * 100
        profWper = ((profW * 1.0) / games) * 100

        print "Game {}:".format(i)
        print " Group A: {} ({}%); Group B: {} ({}%); Prof: {} ({}%)".format(gA, gAper, gB, gBper, prof, profper)
        print "Wins: Group A = {} ({}%); Group B = {} ({}%); Prof: {} ({}%)".format(gAW, gAWper, gBW, gBWper, profW, profWper)
```

I'm thinking I should store the wins in a list, but that's where I'm lost.

Comment: Why is this tagged `chaos`?

Comment: @chrisz Not sure. OP probably wasn't aware that the `chaos` tag has a specific meaning, and is not meant to be used simply when your code is 'chaotic'. I removed.

Comment: Why do you want to store a list of wins instead of just a count as you're already doing? It seems like the only thing you'd do with those lists is take their `len`, so why have them? (If you needed to pass them to `statistics.pstdev` or something, that might be a different story, but it doesn't seem like that's a requirement.)

Comment: Quite simply, you need to create the counter variables for each groups' total number of wins _outside_ of both of the `for`-loops, in the `coinFlip` function's scope. Otherwise, you'll continue to reset them each iteration, losing data. Also, as a related side note, you need to consider renaming your variable names to something clearer. Names like `gB` and `profWper` are cryptic will only serve to cause confusion later in your programs development.

Comment: Make your function return the value (or values) from each run of the simulation and store them in a list. When all runs are done, you should be able to calculate the statistics you want across all of the games played from what's in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The critical problem is that you have reset the long-term counts at the start of every game.  Thus, nobody gets to record more than one win.  This works great for my Monday-night Frisbee games, but is not effective for your assignment.

Return to your psuedo-code and see where the loops and initializations match up.  Here's a code version:

def coinFlip():

```
# Set-up you do only once per program execution
games = input("How many games? ")
tosses = input("How many coin tosses per game? ")
games_won_A = 0
games_won_B = 0
games_won_prof = 0

for i in range(games):
    # Set-up things you do once per game
    tosses_won_A = 0
    tosses_won_B = 0
    tosses_won_prof = 0

    for j in range(tosses):
        # Things you do every toss
        flip1 = random.randint(0, 1)
        flip2 = random.randint(0, 1)
        ...

    # Summary things you do every game
    # ... such as compute percentages

# Summary things you do at the end of the program execution
# ... such as print the overall totals
```

Does that get you moving?

BTW< note that this becomes a *lot* shorter if you put the counters into a list.  For instance, counting the winner of each flip becomes a single line:

```
win_count[flip1 + flip2] += 1
```

`win_count` can be a list of three elements, recording the wins for A, prof, and B, in that order.

Comment: Thanks! Like I said, I'm still new, and it was indeed an indentation error within the function.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't what the OP was looking for, but in general generating random numbers with `numpy` can accomplish this quickly and simply.

```
import numpy as np

# get these from input or wherever
games = 5
tosses = 10
n_coins = 2

experiment = np.random.randint(2,size=(games, tosses, n_coins))
flip_results = experiment.sum(axis=2) # 0 means group A wins, 1 Prof, 2 group B
game_results = np.stack((flip_results == 0, flip_results == 1, flip_results == 2))
game_results = game_results.sum(axis=2)
total_results = game_results.sum(axis=1)
print(game_results, total_results)
```

Comment: I'm unhappy about the `np.stack` bit.  If anyone knows of a cleaner way to figure out the counts of 0s 1s and 2s *per game*, I'm interested.  Note that `np.unique` won't operate per value over individual axes.